# aws glue, how to connect to external database server which not locate in aws cloud？

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to ingest data from an existing database locate in our own network to redshift using aws glue, i can connect it from an EC2 instance, but no idea how to connect it from aws glue。 Would someone give me any advice? I think it would be something magic in VPC setting, but no hints after seraching google.

Answer (score 1):

> Would someone give me any advice?

AWS wrote dedicated articles about this topic:

- [How to access and analyze on-premises data stores using AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-to-access-and-analyze-on-premises-data-stores-using-aws-glue/)
- [Use AWS Glue to run ETL jobs against non-native JDBC data sources](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-aws-glue-to-run-etl-jobs-against-non-native-jdbc-data-sources/)

These would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

#upload jdbc driver to s3 location, in my case "s3://manikantabucket/com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar"
add driver jar file in glue properties bar

##########code
import sys

from pyspark.context import SparkContext

from awsglue.context import GlueContext

from awsglue.transforms import *

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

connection_mysql8_options_source_emp = {
"url": "jdbc:mysql://ec2-2-138-264-235.ap-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3306/mysql",
"dbtable": "db",
"user": "root",
"password": "root",
"customJdbcDriverS3Path": "s3://manikantabucket/com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar",
"customJdbcDriverClassName": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"}

df_emp=df_emp.coalesce(1)

df_emp = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="mysql", connection_options=connection_mysql8_options_source_emp)
S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
frame=df_emp,
connection_type="s3",
format="csv",
connection_options={"path": "s3://manikantabucketo/test/", "partitionKeys": []},
transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3",
)